# I get this noisy result (attached video and blend file) for engraved and beveled text

Tags: animation, bevel

Can someone please enlighten me what am I doing wrong? Why does the boolean difference operator result look so bad?

The bottom of the engraved text is very noisy as you can see in the attached video. Also, I can't get the bevel modifier after the boolean operator modifier to produce a nice glitch free result. I actually had to disable the clamp overlap option because otherwise there's no bevel at all, but I guess this way the bevels around the engraved text gets noisy. Maybe the boolean difference operator and the bevel operator can't play nicely together. I wanted the text to move into the other object, maybe there's another way.

[Blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qvZYzDsQ1Mo-hZrsvE1HcfQLMfd8OEdN/view?usp=sharing)

[Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hezR7maupLVf5CMwGJ9RKTG6mLRzK3UY/view?usp=sharing)

Edit:

Part of the reason why the output is so bad is that I made the cutout invisible by making it transparent using a transparent surface/volume material. Now, that's a bad idea, but I didn't know there was a specific boolean option for that. Silly me.

The other reason could be that bevel for very pointy corners doesn't play nicely with the boolean difference operator. I couldn't figure out what to do about that yet.